# fprintf into a .txt file gives me ‰‰‰‰‱‱‱‱‱‱‱ instead of 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

Tags: c

It's my first try in writing into a file with `c`.

The part making the problem is the following:

```
for (j = 0; j < num_probs; j++) {
    fprintf(dataMy, "%i ", data_my[j]);
}
```

Additional information: `data_my` is an int array filled just with 0 and 1 (a lot of them)

If the code is executed there are just these symbols

```
‰‰‰‰‱‱‱‱‱‱‱
```

instead of

```
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

in my .txt file.

If I change `%i` in `fprintf(dataMy, "%i ", data_my[j])` to `%2i` which gives 2 characters each time printed, but because I use only 0 or 1 (1 character each), one is a spacebar. Or I can write `%i` which works too, but I want to start my .txt file without a spacebar.

Here is my complete program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>

#define num_annos    523
#define num_probs    1910
#define meine_zeile  59

int data[num_annos][num_probs];

void main() {    
    int i, j;
    FILE *f = NULL;
    FILE *dataMy = NULL;

    errno_t err;
    int data_my[num_probs];

    if ((err = fopen_s(&f, "H:\\Hochschule\\Informatik\\UebungenIII\\Daten für A6_15WS_all\\datamatrix_v5_1.txt", "r")) != 0) {
        printf("The file was not opened\n");
    } else {
        printf("Datei erfolgreich geoeffnet!\n\n");

        for (i = 0; i < num_annos; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < num_probs; j++) {
                fscanf_s(f, "%i", &data[i][j]);
                printf("%2i", data[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        fclose(f);
        printf("\n\nEinlesen erfolgreich.\n");
    }

    for (j = 0; j < num_probs; j++) {
        data_my[j] = data[meine_zeile-1][j];
    }

    if ((err = fopen_s(&dataMy, "H:\\Hochschule\\Informatik\\UebungenIII\\Daten für A6_15WS_all\\data_my.txt", "w")) != 0) {
        printf("The file was not opened\n");
    } else {            
        for (j = 0; j < num_probs; j++) {
            fprintf(dataMy, "%i ", data_my[j]);
            printf("%i ", data_my[j]);
        }
        fclose(dataMy);
    }
    getch();
}
```

It reads in 0 and 1 from the `datamatrix_v5_1.txt` (this file is just filled with 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1... and so on), saves one of these lines into the array data_my and thats what I want to print into the `data_my.txt`.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] that enables every one to reproduce the problem you describe.

Comment: That's really weird. Looks a bit like the text is interpreted as UTF-16 or something like that.

Comment: You've probably opened file in binary mode, and write 16bit integers.

Comment: I tried to add a \n after the loop, that doesnt fix it, if i print a \n before the loop, well i have one empty line at the top, but i get 0 and 1.

Comment: @M.93 Please show us your whole program. It seems like you have problems involving wide-character handling. Are you programming on Windows?

Comment: Yes, i am using VisualStudio... i can show you the whole program, its no secret.

Comment: No, do not show us the whole program. Show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @M.93 Seeing the whole program, I'm inclined to believe that this is just an example of Windows-braindeadness. Windows resp. your editor is interpreting the file as UTF-16 when it should be ASCII. Try to explicitly set an encoding when opening the text file and report back if that fixed your problem.

Comment: @FUZxxl

You were completely right, its just a nonesense in the uncoding process of microsofts txt-editor. If i open the txt file with Notepad everything is just fine, same with wordpad.

Do you know how to tell the Editor in which way it should be opened? Otherwise ill stay with Notepad...

Comment: Thx a lot at this point @ every1 who tried to help and especially to you FUZxxl

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The characters ‰ and ‱ have the Unicode code-points `0x2030` and `0x2031` respectively. Encoded as UTF-16 and then interpreted as ASCII, these are `' 0'` and `' 1'` or `'0 '` and `'1 '`, depending on byte-order. It seems like your ASCII output is somehow interpreted as if it was UTF-16.

This can happen if you perform byte-wise output on a wide-character stream. This can also happen because your editor's encoding-detection routine malfunctioned (cf. [Bush hid the facts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_hid_the_facts)). Try to manually set a text encoding when editing the file or use ea different editor.

Comment: Excellent diagnosis. However, the program is not ASCII. It's probably Windows-1250 or Windows-1252.

Comment: @TomBlodget Doesn't matter, 1252 is an extension of ASCII anyway.